# FULL OUTER JOIN with an OR condition

Tags: sql, join, optimization, ssms

I have 2 tables with 2 different id's. I want to join based on the 2 different id's and a few other parameters, but the problem is that the 1 id's don't always match. Sometimes id number 1 will have matches, some times id number 2 will not match any and some times both will match.

Using `full outer join` with an `OR` condition in the `JOIN` clause really slows down my query. Is there a more efficient way of doing this?
I know you can use unions instead in case of inner joins but am not sure how to optimize using outer joins.

```
SELEC A.*, B.*
FROM A
FULL OUTER JOIN  B
    ON  (A.id_1 = B.id_1 or A.id_2 = B.id_2)
    AND A.pay_month = B.pay_month
    AND A.plan = B.plan
```

Comment: can you creae working example using this sql fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f8360c/3

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm . . . This might be sufficient:

```
select A.*, B.*
from A full outer join 
     B
     on A.id_1 = B.id_1 and A.pay_month = B.pay_month and A.plan = B.plan
union  -- intentionally to remove duplicates
select A.*, B.*
from A full outer join 
     B
     on A.id_2 = B.id_2 and A.id_1 <> B.id_1 and A.pay_month = B.pay_month and A.plan = B.plan;
```

This is not 100% equivalent -- for instance, this removes duplicates even within a table.  Also, the `union` adds the overhead of removing duplicates.  But the results may be good for your purposes.

Also, is a `full outer join` really necessary?  I rarely use it in my code.